# How can I add to countries with the same variables?

Tags: javascript

I am m taking a course and I need help with this. How can I Alert ‘You speak Portuguese’ if you are from Brazil or Portugal?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
let country = prompt("what country are you from ?");

if (country === "brazil" && country === "Portugal ") {
  alert("You speak Portuguese");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full example. You need to use the [logical OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) (`||`) instead of the [logical AND operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) (`&&`).

```js
let country = prompt("what country are you from ?");

if (country === "brazil" || country === "Portugal ") {
  alert("You speak Portuguese");
}
```

**EDIT**:

If you want to ignore the capitalization of the user input you could do the following:

```js
let country = prompt("what country are you from ?").toLowerCase();

if (country === "brazil" || country === "portugal") {
  alert("You speak Portuguese");
}
```

Comment: it only works with brazil however, when i refresh and try with portugal it doesnt give me anything

Comment: You need to be careful with capitalization. In your question. `Portugal` starts with a capital letter.

Comment: thanks a lot, sorry am just a beginner and sometimes I just forget about the capital letters. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at my edit if you want to ignore capitalization.

Comment: i used it and it worker perfectly

Comment: hey i want to ask you something

Answer (score 0):

There is no way `country` will simultaneously be `brazil` *and* `Portugal`, you need to check if it's brazil *or* Portugal

```
if (country === "brazil" || country === "Portugal")
```

Comment: this is what they want me to do   Alert ‘You speak Portuguese’ if you are from Brazil or Portugal